# Is it possible to specify explicit type for the parameter in a caller side for PHPDoc

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

There is a method call expression:

```
$session->setUser($this->em->getReference(UserAccount::class, $ownerId));
```

where `setUser` is declared as

```
public function setUser(UserAccount $user): self
```

`$this->em->getReference` being a Doctrines's entity manager method returns `object|null`.

So PhpStorm marks this call as mismatching argument-parameter types.

I surely can split it into 2 statements and type it:

```
/** @var UserAccount $userAccount */
$userAccount = $this->em->getReference(UserAccount::class, $ownerId);
$session->setUser($userAccount);
```

But may be there is a way to do that inline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's possible with what they call [PHPStorm advanced metadata](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata). As far as I understand you want something like this (you may need to experiment)

```
override(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface::getReference(0), map([
    '' => '@'
]))
```

Comment: Wow, I had no idea this existed, this is fantastic

Comment: Wow that's ugly, but answers my question perfectly, thanks

Comment: @zerkms It is working for you? Did you implement the code exactly like in the answer or did you make some adjustment to get it work? I mean exept incluiding this in a namespace PHPSTORM_META{}

Comment: @sdespont nah, it's to ugly to even try: I don't like too much configuration for my tools, if it cannot be inferred, then let be it as-is.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no such language feature and you can rely only on PHPDoc or Symfony plugin for PHPStorm.

Since [Symfony plugin claims](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7219-symfony-plugin) only next features:

- QueryBuilder support, including chaining and nested methods
- References and TypeProvider for doctrine getRepository
- TypeProvider for EntityRepository::find/findOneBy/findAll/findBy
- Field and relations resolving and annotation and yaml

you can use `find*()` methods or PHPDoc solution shown above. Please keep in mind, according to possibility to return `null` by Doctrine's methods the plugin way still show you an warning about passing `null` as not nullable argument.

There is a Github issue about [getReference() resolving](https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin/issues/441).